# ASPX Page formatting

Tags: asp.net

I have Panel that needs to have a button beside it but have been unsuccessful in formatting it. Currently this is what I have.

```
   <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="form" ID="panSomeParameters"></asp:Panel> 
            <asp:Button runat="server"  CssClass="form" ID="btnSomeButton" Text="Button" />
```

[image]

Basically I need the Button in the blue area.

Comment: Which one is panel here? Green or blue one? Also did you try putting the panel and button inside a `<span></span>` element?

Comment: @SivaGopal my apologies for any confusion. The green is the panel and the the blue is where the button needs to go instead of below the panel. I tried putting the panel in a DIV but with no success. I'll give the span a try.

Comment: <span>
  <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="form" ID="panSomeParameters"></asp:Panel> 
            <asp:Button runat="server"  CssClass="form" ID="btnSomeButton" Text="Button" /> 
   </span>                              I tried this but same result.

Comment: In that case reliable option would be `<table><tr><td><asp:Panel/></td><td><asp:Button/></td></tr></table>`. Give it a try.

Comment: @SivaGopal using tables for layout is a 1990s idea and creates horrendous, unreadable and unmaintainble markup on larger pages. Improvements in CSS and better adherence to web standards over the last 20 years make the idea completely redundant. It's also goes against the principle of semantic markup - i.e. that markup should be used for what they actually are and what they represent, not just how they look. Tables are for displaying tabular data, not for general presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set your Panel display to "inline-block" as panel is rendered as Div and div is a block element so it will cover the whole row. I have set width and height also so panel will contain space on the view.

```
 <asp:Panel runat="server" style="display:inline-block;width:100px;height:20px;" CssClass="form" ID="panSomeParameters"></asp:Panel> 
        <asp:Button runat="server"  CssClass="form" ID="btnSomeButton" Text="Button" />
```

If it helps then accept the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could give them both a class and set the `float` to `left`.

```
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="float-left">
        Contents
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="float-left" />
</div>

<style>
    .float-left {
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Intellisense does not give me the option for Style

Comment: That seems very unlikely, see https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Comment: @AndyWilliams so what? Intellisense is wrong a surprising amount of the time. And it's just an IDE tool anyway. That doesn't mean you can't use the tag in your page. If you want to know if a tag exists, then you can always [look it up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) . Of course an alternative to an in-page style block here would be to add the rule to your .css file instead. I would guess VDWWD only did it this way just to make this example simpler.

Comment: @ADyson, yeah the inline style is just for this demo. @ Andy, normally you would have the classes in an external css file.